# unix cat $0|sed -n '/^# [hH]\*/p'|sed 's/^# [hH]\*//g'|pg

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I am new to UNIX..
Can please anyone explain me this line of code...

```
cat $0|sed -n '/^#  [hH]\*/p'|sed 's/^#  [hH]\*//g'|pg
```

Comment: This might help: https://explainshell.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be summed up as:
extract the lines starting with `#  h*` or `#  H*` in the current script file,
with the starting `#  [hH]*` removed,
and pass to the `pg` program.

Explanation:

- `$0` is the name of the file being executed. If you run a script as `./path/to/script.sh` it will be that path.
- The first `sed` prints only the lines start with `#  [hH]\*`, where `[hH]` means `h` or `H`, and `\*` means the literal `*` character. The `^` means "start of a line".
- The second `sed` replaces the starting `#  [hH]\*` with nothing, effectively removing the pattern. It has the `g` flag to perform the replacement as many times as there is a match, but it's pointless here, since the `^` guarantees that there will be only match.
- I don't know what `pg` does...

It's effectively the same as this simpler (and safer) pipeline:

```
sed -n 's/^#  [hH]\*//p' "$0" | pg
```